# Popovers without jQuery

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I've been implementing popovers with AngularStrap and AngularUI Bootstrap.  I can get both of these frameworks to get popovers working alongside the full jQuery library, but not when I exclude jQuery.  I know that Angular includes a version of jQuery called jQlite, and supposedly that should be all you need to implement these other frameworks. Here's my question, is it even possible to implement popovers in Angular without the full jQuery library?

Comment: Don't see any reason why *anything* shouldn't be possible without jQuery, given that bare JavaScript without any extra helper libraries isn't productive to write, but should be always sufficient. Say, here's a library (15 seconds searching) that shows [popovers using ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-confirm) without relying on jQuery. No idea whenever jQLite would be useful or not, though.

Comment: Dont quite understand the question - look at the documentation for angularstrap, here is the official example for popovers -> http://plnkr.co/edit/kNf8QGna5fWokr46MEOf?p=preview ... no jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the [ui-bootstrap homepage](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)  states:

> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on
>   Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or
>   Bootstrap's JavaScript is required

[AngularStrap's page](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) doesn't mention any dependancy on jQuery either.

So, to answer your question, yes, you can implment the popovers without jQuery being included in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the AngularUI popups working either, but was successful with Angular-Strap. I put together an example plunker that may help you out. I used something similar on my site.

[Angular Strap popup directive (on Plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/lxL65Q/preview)](http://embed.plnkr.co/lxL65Q/preview)

I'm using the popup for images. The 'image-popup' directive is placed in an img tag, where it expects a src attribute. Libraries I needed were the Bootstrap styles, Angular JS, and the Angular Strap script and template files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="popupApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<head>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/v2.1.3/dist/angular-strap.js" data-semver="2.1.3" data-require="angular-strap@2.1.3"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/master/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" data-semver="2.1.3" data-require="angular-strap@2.1.3"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Using Angular JS and Angular-Strap to create a popup image viewer</h1>
<figure class="col-sm-4">
  <img image-popup alt="lolcat" class="img-popup-source" src="http://obeythekitty.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/lolcat_flying_cat.jpg" />
  <figcaption>Leaping Lolcats!</figcaption>
</figure>
</body>

</html>
```

The example app code looks like this:

```
// Include a reference to ngStrap like this
var popupApp = angular.module('popupApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

// This demo doesn't really need a controller but hey.
popupApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

// Directive that displays an image within an Angular Strap popup.
// This directive should only be applied to an img, as it expects a 'src' attribute.
popupApp.directive('imagePopup', ['$popover', '$compile', '$window', function($popover, $compile, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var myPopover = $popover(element, {
          title: attrs.popupTitle,
          template: 'angular-strap-popover-tpl.html',
          html: true,
          trigger: 'manual',
          autoClose: true,
          transclude: true,
          scope: scope,
          animation: 'am-fade'
       });

      // Toggle the popover closed when you click it
      scope.closeMe = function() {
        myPopover.toggle();
      };

      // Toggle the popover closed when you click the original smaller image.
      element.on('click', function(element) {
        myPopover.toggle();
      });
    },

    // Isolate scope, load the popup template image's src from the src attribute of the original image
    scope: {
      popupImageSrc: '@src'
    }

  }
}]);
```

You may want to fiddle with the popup options and styles. Here's the popup template I used:

```
<div class="popover">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title" ng-bind="title" ng-show="title"></h3>
  <div class="popover-content" ng-click="closeMe()"><img ng-src="{{popupImageSrc}}"></div>
</div>
```

Angular Strap's components worked well for me, and they have a builder that lets you put together just the components that you need. I did have one challenge in testing this directive on my site though. I also use AngularUI (for the carousel) and there was a namespace collision on a 'tooltip' module shared by both libraries. I never did figure out how to work around that one.

I hope this is helpful, all the best.